# Do people place coal or charcoal in a "hookaa"?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

What is the name of the thing that people put on the hookaa?

Is it called *coal* or *charcoal* or both? I am confused about it.

Comment: I've never used a hookah (or seen one in use) but my guess is that it would be charcoal since, unlike coal, charcoal burns without smoke, being almost pure carbon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to ID parts of a hookah, and is not about learning English. At best, additional reference material needs to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hookah) a **hookah** is a type of elaborate apparatus, also called a water pipe, used for smoking tobacco or weed (marijuana).

[image]

> In India and Pakistan the Hindi-Urdu word *huqqa* is used (Devanagari: हुक़्क़ा, Nastaleeq: حقّہ); this word is the origin of the English word **"hookah"**. The widespread use of the Indian word "hookah" in the English language is a result of the colonization in British India (1858–1947), when large numbers of expatriate Britons first sampled the water pipe.

After a little more digging, I found that **charcoal** is the fuel most commonly used. The tobacco and charcoal is burned in the top chamber in order to produce smoke.

[image]

> For those of you that don’t know, a hookah is heated by hookah **charcoal**. Some hookah charcoals are easier to light and arrange than others, but they all serve one common purpose: to heat a hookah bowl. Heat management and maintaining the heat transfer is the key to gaining the perfect hookah smoke. [Source](https://www.hookah-shisha.com/hookahlove/70-how-to-smoke-a-hookah-hookah-charcoal-and-heat-management.html)

The Oxford Dictionary defines charcoal as

> **charcoal**
>   1. A porous black solid, consisting of an amorphous form of carbon, **obtained as a residue when wood, bone, or other organic matter** is heated in the absence of air.
>
> - *[‘France still produced ample wood for charcoal; British ironmasters had to turn to coal.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/charcoal)*

### Coal vs Charcoal

- **Coal** is a black organic rock found below the ground, and as such needs to be mined. It is a fossil fuel which was formed millions of years ago.

[image]

- **Charcoal** is also a black substance which is obtained  by the long and slow process of burning wood or other combustible substances in the absence of oxygen. It is less dense and more porous than coal.

[image]

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Start-a-Hookah

Answer (score 3):

Charcoal is a particular material.  Coal, however, can mean both the material dug from the ground, or a hot burning piece of wood, charcoal, coal, etc.

[Coal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coal):

1. a black or brownish-black hard substance within the earth that is used as a fuel
2. a piece of coal or charcoal especially when burning
3. a glowing piece of wood from a fire

"I placed a coal in the hookah" would be the 2nd or 3rd meanings.  "I ordered more coal for the furnace" would be the 1st meaning.

So to answer your question, you could use both words.
 * "Put another coal in the hookah."
 * "Do you have any charcoal for the hookah?"